# How do I align items to the right while maintaining default height-behaviour?

Tags: css

I have a tricky layout I'm trying to achive. Primarily, the left column is important here.

[image]

In my code sample below, the content is aligned to the left. How can I get the content-areas to align to the right, but still maintain their height, so that the white area ends up below the green area? Bonus if you can get rid of the wrappers!

I have tried text-align right, float: right and position:absolute, the first one has no effect and the other two colapses the height to 0

We cannot assume any height of the content the width is a max width and a percentage of the total page widht.

Below is my full markup:

```css
body {
  width: 61.8047%;
}
 
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.question__wrapper {
  background: #009B58;
}
.question {
  max-width: 742px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}
.answer {
  max-width: 742px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
}
.context {
  max-width: 742px;
  background: #4A4A4A;
  width: 38.1953%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="se">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="question__wrapper">
    <div class="question">
      content
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="answer__wrapper">
      <div class="answer">
        <h2 class="answer__header">Svar</h2>
        <div class="answer__text">
          content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <aside class="context">
      <div class="context__cta">
        <h2>Logo</h2>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <script src="javascripts/application.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
This will make more sense in full screen-mode!
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "text-align:right has no effect", because it has. It works, even! Unless I'm completely in the dark as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "getting rid of the wrappers". Just remove the tags? [Here, a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/22ck6gyr/).

Comment: @MrLister, yes! Get rid of the tags.

Comment: I meant, I don't know what the problem was. All I did was remove the tags and add `text-align:right` to the css. But you sounded like you already tried that, and failed. Does the fiddle work for you?

Comment: If you look at my image, you can se, I try to align the contents, like .answer to the right, not align the text inside the contents.

Comment: In my jsfiddle, the contents are lined out to the right. Is that not how you want it?